# Get places inside a rectangle google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is it possible to get places inside a rectangle or any other shape in google maps api? Basically, I want a user to draw a rectangle on the map and my program should find all the places(e.g restaurants) that are inside that rectangle.
I was able to this with a circle, but I don't know how to that with a rectangle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you do it within a circle?

Comment: @geocodezip, I got the radius of the circle and used that radius for the radius of the places api. The same can't be done for rectangle, as rectangle does not have radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to search places within a rectangle using the places library of Maps JavaScript API v3, you should use a bounds parameter in your PlaceSearchRequest object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceSearchRequest

> **bounds** Type:  LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral
>
> The bounds within which to search for Places. Both location and radius will be ignored if bounds is set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have already figured out that part myself. But there seems to be an error, the places out of the shape are also sown: http://savepic.org/8484970.png Do you know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Bounds are a strong suggestion, but by no means a constraint. Same goes for radius search.